# VBA code to disconnect from Essbase Connection

Tags: vba, excel, hyperion, essbase

I tried writing the VBA to connect yo Hyperion Essbase to connect to multiple sheets and the connection is successful

```
X = EssVConnect("[Macro.xls] Sheet1, sheet2,sheet3 ", "Uname", "Pwd", "Server", "Applicationname", "DB")
            If X = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Essbase connect is successful")
            Else
            MsgBox ("Essbase connection failed.")
            End If
```

But to disconnect from the multiple sheets it is not working with the below code and it is returning the Value 0 instead of -4

```
Y = EssVDisconnect("Sheet1, sheet2, sheet3")
            If Y = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Essbase connect is successful")
            Else
            MsgBox ("Essbase connection failed.")
            End If
```

Please let me what changes i have to do so that I can disconnect from the connected database

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to connect and disconnect multiple sheets in one command, but if your connection command works I'd assume the disconnect should work as well. You omitted the name of the workbook in your disconnect string though. Try listing the sheets the same way you did in your connect string:

```
Y = EssVDisconnect("[Macro.xls] Sheet1, sheet2, sheet3")
```